# Как каждому элементу поставить знак перед и после?

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```
Object.keys(etfABData).forEach(function (i) {
            const text = etfABData[i].symbol.text;
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                text[i] = "_" + text[i] + ',';
            }
            
        })
```

тут неудачная попытка
есть объект etfABData и нужно каждому элементу text добавить в конце "," а в начале "_"
Заранее благодарю

Comment: так мб обратно в объект его вписать надо потом?

Comment: не понял о чем вы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так пишите сразу в объект

```
Object.keys(etfABData).forEach(function (i) {
    etfABData[i].symbol.text = "_" + etfABData[i].symbol.text + ",";           
})
```

а в вашем коде

1. каждой букве слова ставится вначале "_" и в конец ","
2. никуда результат не записывается, поскольку вы работаете с локальной переменной text